# How can I find a web application's document root using a path traversal vulnerability?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, webserver, operating-systems, web-service

I am performing a penetration testing on an application hosted on an Ubuntu environment.

So using a path traversal vulnerability, I can download any file.

The API web application runs as root (shadow and brute-force are already my friends). Funny situation: I can not find the web root folder.

What I have tried:

- Search for logs that can lead me to the path. nginx or apache2 is not there.
- Search for nginx, apache2 or other configuration files
- Search for common directories of web roots (https://serverfault.com/questions/144598/where-should-the-web-server-root-directory-go-in-linux)
- Bash histories of all users

What else should I try?

Comment: What about the /opt location?

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox no luck :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the traversal vulnerability to read

```
/proc/self/environ
```

This prints out environment variables among other thread information.

Look for a environment variable called DOCUMENT_ROOT